# implementing DBSCAN in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, dbscan

I studing ML course and we got homework to implement ours own DNSCAN .
I'm almost finished but i'm stuck at the end. I benn stearing for 30m on the code and Im realy can get what wrong.
ther seems no error and the compiler works great on the code.

I could use some of your help .

```
def __init__(self,data,e,minPoint):
    self.data=data
    self.e=e
    self.minPoint=minPoint
    self.train=np.zeros(len(data))-2 #-2 label unidentified 
    
    self.distance_matrix = np.linalg.norm(data[np.newaxis, ...] -data[ :, np.newaxis, :],axis=-1)
    self.distance_matrix += np.diag([np.inf]*len(data))


def region_neighbours(self,core_point):
    neighbours= np.nonzero(self.distance_matrix[core_point, :] <= self.e)
    return neighbours[0]




def expandCluster(self,core_point):
    cluster_index=[]
    cluster_index.append(core_point)
    cluster_now=DBSCAN.region_neighbours(self,core_point)
    if len(cluster_now)>=self.minPoint:
        for i in cluster_now:
            cluster_next=DBSCAN.region_neighbours(self,i)
            if len(cluster_next)>=self.minPoint:
                flag=True
                for b in cluster_index:
                    if b==i:
                        flag=False
                if flag:
                    cluster_index.append(i)
                    cluster_now=cluster_next
    return cluster_index
                
    

def fit(self):
    cluster_label=1
    for i in range(len(self.data)):
        if self.train[i]==-2:
            cluster=DBSCAN.expandCluster(self,i)
            if len(cluster)<self.minPoint :
                self.train[i]=-1 # (-1 label as noise)
            else:
                for b in cluster:
                    if self.train[b]==-2:
                        self.train[b]=cluster_label
                cluster_label+=1
    return self.data,self.train




    
    
    
    


iris = datasets.load_iris()
dataset = iris.data

data=DBSCAN(dataset,0.5,3)
data,train=data.fit()
print(train)
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the issue? Please post a [mre].

Comment: sorry my first post.  Im not sure what the problom, but for some reson after I run fit() it gives mes verrey diffret train then if i ran on sklearn. I thinsk something in my code in fit doesnt run correct and makes worng labels. hope now I make more sense

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.